# Не работает программа, которая вычисляет кол-во различных объектов в списке

Tags: python, объекты

Прохожу сейчас [курс](https://stepik.org/course/512/syllabus) на степике по питону, и в одном из [степов](https://stepik.org/lesson/24458/step/9?unit=6765) попалась задача:

> Реализуйте программу, которая будет вычислять количество **различных**
> объектов в списке. Два объекта a и b считаются различными, если a is b
> равно False.
>
> Вашей программе доступна переменная с названием **objects**, которая
> ссылается на **список**, содержащий не более 100 объектов. Выведите
> количество различных объектов в этом списке. Рассмотрим пример:
>
> `objects = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3] # будем считать, что одинаковые числа соответствуют одинаковым объектам, а различные – различным`
>
> Тогда все различные объекты являют собой **множество {1, 2, 3}** ﻿.
> Таким образом, количество различных объектов равно **трём**.

Я написал программу, которая не работает:

```
n = len(objects) 
count = 0 
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        if id(objects[i]) == id(objects[j]):
            count += 1 # считаю кол-во повторяющихся(по id) элементов 
print(n - count) #отнимаю это кол-во от общего числа
```

В самом степе есть решение:

```
n = len(objects)
ans = n
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
        if id(objects[i]) == id(objects[j]):
            ans -= 1
            break

print(ans)
```

Я проверил свою на следующих примерах:

objects = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]

objects = [1, 2, 1, 5, True, False, True, 'false', [], [1,2], [1,2]]

И она выдает те же рез-ты, что и правильная, но тест не проходит. Вот хотел узнать почему? Потому что, как мне кажется, моя делает то же самое(подсчет повторов в списке) только направления движения второго цикла разные. Если кто-то понял, почему моя программа не решает задачу, объясните пожалуйста почему или хотя бы предложите начальные данные, на которых она выдаст неправильный результат. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а на что степик ругается?

Comment: Тут дело не в плюсе-минусе, а в break. Если в списке есть не два, а `k` одинаковых объектов, то вы в сумме вычтете `k*(k-1)/2` вместо `k-1`. Соответственно тест простой: `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: Могу предположить, что ошибка из-за несоблюдения стандарта pep8,  то есть вы должны написать 4-ую строку так: for j in range(i + 1, n):

Comment: @Stanislav Enyagin В степике проходятся два теста, а остальные 21: Wrong answer

Comment: @EzikBro да действительно, все так и есть... Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @Tehnorobot в моей программе вроде есть же "i+1", а в правильной и не нужно

Comment: Tehnorobot, вероятно, имел в виду, что там нужно поставить пробелы, но вообще говоря это совершенно не важно на автоматических системах проверки вроде степика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути вопроса вам уже объяснили в комментариях (дело в волшебном `break`), но я помимо этого хочу сделать пару примечаний.

1. Странно, что вы в явном виде используете `id`, хотя в задании прямо сказано использовать "синтаксический сахар" `is` (который проверяет именно равенство `id`). Т.е. вместо:

```
id(objects[i]) == id(objects[j])
```

Должно быть:

```
objects[i] is objects[j]
```

2. А если уж использовать `id`, то можно решить эту задачу гораздо проще и короче. Хотя, возможно, вы ещё не проходили `set` и `map`:

```
print(len(set(map(id, objects))))
```

Comment: Я в конце концов так и решил через множества( в комментариях на степе подсказали). А эта программа - один из первых набросков, просто когда увидел в решениях похожее(выше), захотелось разобраться почему оно работает, а мой код - нет. В любом случае спасибо за ответ